# Spark Partition Overwrite Mode not working properly when upgrading to Spark 3.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partition, overwrite

When upgrading from Spark version 2.4.3 to 3.3.0 `Spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")` no longer seems to work on some scripts. The write ended up deleting whole directories rather than the specified partitions, I found that adding `.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")` to the write statement allowed for the overwrite to work properly. I listed the conf settings and saw that Spark did indeed set the partitionOverwriteMode to dynamic so I don't understand why this only worked once adding the option to the write? I also have another script that I upgraded that only uses the `Spark.conf.set` and works just fine. Has anyone else encountered this issue?